# "Undefined function or variable" loadAudioPlugin

Tags: matlab, vst

I am trying to run [this simple](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/loadaudioplugin.html) command on Matlab to load a VST:

```
hostedPlugin = loadAudioPlugin(pluginpath)
```

However, I am getting the following error: `Undefined function or variable 'loadAudioPlugin'.`

What's wrong? I can't seem to figure it out... This is the output I get when I type the "ver" command:

```
...
Audio System Toolbox                                  Version 1.2         (R2017a)
...
```

The Audio system toolbox seems to be installed correctly. And the path is set correctly apparently, I can see the "loadAudioPlugin.p" file in the compiled folder.

[image: Path Matlab]

Any ideas why Matlab says the loadAudioPlugin is not a function??

Comment: Can you try with `restoredefaultpath; rehash toolboxcache;`?

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work :/